# How to reset a specific stack navigator from outside of it?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm making an app using react-navigation with react-native.

The structure of my app is,

```
Main Tab
  - Tab 1 (Stack)
    - screen A
    - screen B
    - screen C
  - Tab 2 (Stack)
    - screen D
    - screen E
    - screen F
```

What I want to do is **reset Tab 1 (Stack Navigator) at the specific time** and do not navigate to Tab 1.

if a user is located in screen F, I just want to reset Tab 1 (Stack) without letting the user move to Tab 1.

So I think dispatching navigation actions should be triggered outside of these react components, somewhere like `resetHelper.js`

But I can't figure out how to reset a specific stack without navigating that stack.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if you were in a specific stack, you would reset via `this.props.navigation.reset()` but since you want to reset one stack from another stack you will need to use a `NavigationService` for the `StackNavigator` that needs to be reset.

Read [this help guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html) to see how you can create a `NavigationService`.

Once you have a `NavigationService` setup, edit the `NavigationService.js` to this:

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function reset(index = 0, actions) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    StackActions.reset({
      index,
      actions
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  reset,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Then from any function in any file, do this:

```
import {reset} from NavigationService.js
//your other code and functions here.
reset(0, actions)
```

Read more [about it here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset).